# C# UWP Login form checking credentials in MySQL remote database

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp, windows-10-universal

I got stuck after couple of hours of research. I'm trying to make a basic Universal Windows App with login form - after clicking a button, credentials in textboxes are checked with remote MySQL database. If valid, app shoud navigate to another specified page. If not, error message is displayed.

I can't find error in my code below. After clicking the button Windows' blue circle spins and after couple of seconds returns to VS2017. No errors and warnings. State.ToString() returns 'Open' so I do have a connection with DB. What I'm doing wrong?

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    const string connString = "server=my_server;pwd=pass;uid=user_id;database=mydb;persistsecurityinfo=True";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DbConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private bool DataValidation(string user, string pass)
    {
        DbConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username=@user AND Password=@pass;");

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (login.Read())
        {
            conn.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string user = UserTextBox.Text;
        string pass = PassTextBox.Text;

        if (user == "" || pass == "")
        {
            StatusTextBlock.Text = ("No emty fields allowed. Try again...");
            return;
        }

        bool loginSuccessful = DataValidation(user, pass);

        if (loginSuccessful)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), null);
        }
        else
        {
            StatusTextBlock.Text = "Invalid e-mail or password. Try again...";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `State.ToString()` What is `State`? It isn't in your code.

Comment: I would suggest moving `MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);` inside of `DataValidation` and removing `DbConnection`. Then use a `using` block to Dispose (Close) it automatically.

Comment: Nope it is not in my code above, but StatusTextBox.Text = conn.State.ToString() returns connection state which seems to be open

Comment: @mjwills I've made changes, I've added `using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString)) {  }` into `DataValidation` no effect

Comment: now debuuging stoped at `MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();` System.InvalidOperationException: „Connection must be valid and open. So it seems I don't have connection?

Comment: @mjwills and somethign's wrong with 'bool loginSuccessful = DataValidation(user, pass);'

Comment: ok, finally I made it to work, many thanks for help

Comment: How did you make it work?

Comment: @mjwills `MySqlCommand` was missing connection parameter `conn` and i had to open cmd connection with `cmd.Connection.Open();` I have posted my complete solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Complete working solution:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Project
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    const string connString = "server=server_name;user id=uid;pwd=password;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=db_name";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool DataValidation(string user, string pass)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT " +
            "Username, Password " +
            "FROM users " +
            "WHERE Username=@user AND Password=@pass;", conn))
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (login.Read())
            {
                conn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string user = UserTextBox.Text;
        string pass = PassBox.Password;

        if (user == "" || pass == "")
        {
            StatusTextBlock.Text = ("Your text");
            return;
        }

        bool loginSuccessful = DataValidation(user, pass);

        if (loginSuccessful)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), null);
        }
        else
        {
            StatusTextBlock.Text = "Your text";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would recommend removing `cmd.Connection = conn;` and replacing `if (login.Read())
            {
                conn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Close();
                return false;
            }` with `return login.Read();`

Comment: thanks for additional improvements, works like a charm